# NDSolve for unsteady Taylor-Goldstein equation, can't use MethodOfLines

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a relatively simple system of linear PDE in two variables (z,t). The equations are basically the  Navier-stokes equations linearized around a constant background velocity profile with a source term for the temperature equation.

I have after a lot of effort gotten NDSolve to actually solve the equation, but when I try to use "MethodOfLines", I get a bunch of errors. Here is my code:

```
With[{U = Cos[Pi z / 1.2] - 2 Cos[Pi z / 1.2],
  Q = Piecewise[{{Sin[Pi z/.4], z < .4}}, 0]},
pde1 = {
  (* vorticity and theta equation *) 
  D[\[Omega][z, t], t]  + I k U \[Omega][z, t] - 
    w[z, t]  D[U, z, z]  == I k \[Theta][z, t] ,
  D[\[Theta][z, t], t]  + I k U \[Theta][z, t] == -w [z, t] + Q ,
  (* vorticity inversion *)

  Derivative[2, 0][w][z, t] - k^2 w[z, t] == I k \[Omega][z, t],
  Derivative[1, 0][w][2, t] + k w[2, t] == 0, w[0, t] == 0,
  (* intial condition *)
  \[Omega][z, 0] == 0, \[Theta][z, 0] == 
    0, w[z, 0] == 0 };

sol = NDSolve[
    pde1 /. {k -> 1}, { \[Omega], \[Theta], w}, {t, 0, 200}, {z, 0, 2},
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
      {"MethodOfLines",
        "TemporalVariable" -> t}}] // First]
```

And these are the error messages I get:

```
NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations. >>

NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable z. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>

NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions. >>

First::nofirst:  has zero length and no first element. >>
```

I find this confusing for several reasons.

1. I should not need to specify an initial condition for `w`, since it has no time derivative and is diagnosed from the vorticity variable `omega` using the Laplacian solve. However, if I leave that term out, I get complaints about not specifying enough initial conditions.
2. I have specified two boundary conditions for `w` for a second order bvp, but it still complains. There are no other z-derivatives in my PDE. What gives?

Why am I getting these errors with "MethodOfLines" but not with `Method->Automatic`?

Since NDSolve seems to be getting very confused, is it possible to separate the "vorticity inversion" part of my PDE into its own NDSolve?

I really appreciate your help since I am Mathematica newb, and I am finding NDSolve to be a real pain to debug.

Comment: `Derivative[1, 0] w[2, t] + k w[2, t] == 0` should be `Derivative[1, 0] [w][2, t] + k w[2, t] == 0`.  Please check your equations for other typos.

Comment: I corrected the typo, and I get the same error. In fact, if I replace that robin boundary condition with the Dirichlet condition w[2,t] == 0, I still get the same error.

Comment: If I use `DirichletCondition[w[z, t] == 0, True]`  instead of `w[0,t] ==0, w[2,t] == 0` NDSolve does return something.  Now how can I get my robin condition to work?

Comment: Although `DirichletCondition` produces a solution, it does not look like a stable solution.  In fact, it is unclear to me whether `NDSolve` is capable of solving `pde1` without preprocessing, as described in the example, *Combined Elliptic-Parabolic PDE in 1D*, in [DAE Examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html#1220709306), which you might use as a basis for solving this problem.  By the way, the first warning message given in the quesiton is to be expected, and the second probably arises when `NDSolve` attempts to eliminate `w`.

Comment: Ok. I have been working on a manually discretized solution. I guess it was a kind of naive of me to hope for a way to solve this problem with one function call.  That link is pretty helpful. It seems a little more readable then the "Method of Lines" document.

Comment: `NDSolve` can do a lot, but not everything.  For instance, it cannot do integro-differential equations, to which your system is akin.  (One way to eliminate `w` is to integrate the third equation with `DSolve`, although that does not get you closer to a final answer.)  By the way, you should edit your question to correct the typo we discussed earlier.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about why `NDSolve` fails, but managed to solve your PDE system by eliminating `ω` and `θ` first and discretizing the obtained PDE to a set of ODEs and adding proper option to `NDSolve`.

First, by observing the PDE system

```
With[{k = 1, U = Cos[(Pi z)/(12/10)] - 2 Cos[(Pi z)/(12/10)], 
     Q = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{Sin[(Pi z)/(4/10)], z < 4/10}}, 0]}, 
   pde = {D[ω[z, t], t] + I k U ω[z, t] - w[z, t] D[U, z, z] == 
          I k θ[z, t], 
   D[θ[z, t], t] + I k U θ[z, t] == -w[z, t] + Q, 
        Derivative[2, 0][w][z, t] - k^2 w[z, t] == I k ω[z, t]}; 
    ic = {ω[z, 0] == 0, θ[z, 0] == 0, w[z, 0] == 0}; 
    bc = {Derivative[1, 0][w][2, t] + k w[2, t] == 0, w[0, t] == 0}; ]
```

it's easy to notice `ω` and `θ` can be eliminated:

```
funtheta = Function[{z, t}, #] &[θ[z, t] /. First@Solve[pde[[1]], θ[z, t]]]

funomega = Function[{z, t}, #] &[ω[z, t] /. First@Solve[pde[[-1]], ω[z, t]]]

{neweq, newic, 
  newbc} = {pde[[2]], ic, bc} //. {θ -> funtheta, ω -> funomega} // 
  Simplify

(* {Sin[(5*Pi*z)/2]*(-1 + UnitStep[-(2/5) + z]) + w[z, t] + 
       (1/36)*(-36 + 25*Pi^2)*Cos[(5*Pi*z)/6]^2*w[z, t] + 
       (1/36)*I*(-72 + 25*Pi^2)*Cos[(5*Pi*z)/6]*Derivative[0, 1][w][z, t] + 
       Derivative[0, 2][w][z, t] + Cos[(5*Pi*z)/6]^2*
         Derivative[2, 0][w][z, t] + 2*I*Cos[(5*Pi*z)/6]*
         Derivative[2, 1][w][z, t] == Derivative[2, 2][w][z, t], 

   {w[z, 0] == Derivative[2, 0][w][z, 0], 
     I*(-36 + 25*Pi^2)*Cos[(5*Pi*z)/6]*w[z, 0] + 
         36*(Derivative[0, 1][w][z, 0] + I*Cos[(5*Pi*z)/6]*
                Derivative[2, 0][w][z, 0] - Derivative[2, 1][w][z, 0]) == 0, 
     w[z, 0] == 0}, 

   {w[2, t] + Derivative[1, 0][w][2, t] == 0, 
     w[0, t] == 0}} *)
```

The `newic` still looks a bit complicated, let's analyze it further:

```
First@Solve@newic
(* {Derivative[0, 1][w][z, 0] -> Derivative[2, 1][w][z, 0], 
    Derivative[2, 0][w][z, 0] -> 0, w[z, 0] -> 0} *)
```

It's not hard to notice the `newic` is actually equivalent to:

```
newic = {Derivative[0, 1][w][z, 0] == 0, w[z, 0] == 0}
```

Now we have a single PDE with simple i.c. and b.c., maybe `NDSolve` can solve it? Sadly it's not true:

```
lb = 0; rb = 2; tend = 200;
NDSolve[{neweq, newic, newbc}, {w}, {z, lb, rb}, {t, 0, tend}]
```

> NDSolve::icfail

But luckily `NDSolve` can handle it after the PDE is discretized into a set of ODEs (the `pdetoode` is a general purpose function for discretizing PDE to ODE, its definition can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).):

```
xdifforder = 4; torder = 2;

points = 100;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];
ptoo = pdetoode[w[z, t], t, grid, xdifforder];
odevar = w /@ grid;

odeic = newic // ptoo;    
odebc = With[{sf = 100}, diffbc[{t, torder}, sf]@newbc // ptoo];
odeq = Delete[#, {{1}, {-1}}] &@(neweq // ptoo);

wsollst = NDSolveValue[{odeq, odeic, odebc}, odevar, {t, 0, tend}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Timing in v9.0.1: 11.5454 second *)
(* Timing in v12.3.1: 18.9494 second *)

wsol = rebuild[wsollst, grid, 2]

ωsol = funomega /. w -> wsol

θsol = funtheta //. {w -> wsol, ω -> funomega};

Animate[Plot[wsol[x, t] // {Re@#, Im@#} & // Evaluate, {t, 0, tend}, 
  PlotRange -> 60], {x, lb, rb}]
```

[image]

**Remark:**

1. `points` should be large enough.
2. `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep@ `` in the definition of `Q` is necessary, or `NDSolve` will spit out `ndnum` warning and fails. It's probably a bug of `NDSolve`.
3. The "strange" definition for `odebc` is necessary, if one simply forms a DAE system with the discretized b.c. i.e. use something like `odebc = newbc // ptoo;`, `NDSolve` will fail again. If you want to know more about the definition of `odebc`, check this [obscure tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612). (Particularly the part about **Boundary Conditions**. )
4. It seems to be OK to set `sf` to any non-negative value, I just use `100` out of habit, but do notice it's necessary to make `sf > 0` when i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent.
5. It's necessary to eliminate `ω` and `θ` first, a direct discretization still fails.